# How can I show this statement.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that there is no holomorphic fuction $f$ in the unit disc $D$ that  extends continuously to boundary of $D$ such that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} ~for~ z\in \partial( D) $.

I tried to apply maximum principle but I couln't find the way to prove it.

Help me please.

I just update the full statement and I think it probably assume it is not constant fuction.

Thank you.

Comment: The constant function $f(z)=0$ is holomorphic on the unit disk and extends continuously to the boundary of the disk. Are you sure you haven't misunderstood or misquoted the exercise?

Comment: I think the word "non-constant" may be missing in the OP.

Comment: The non-constant function $f(z)=z$ is holomorphic on the unit disk and extends continuously to the boundary of the disk.=

Comment: Could the upvoters explain how they understand the question?

Answer (score 6):

If such a function existed, then for all $r < 1$ you'd have $\int_{|z| = r} f(z)\,dz = 0$ by Cauchy's Theorem. Taking limits as $r \rightarrow 1$ would give $\int_{|z| = 1} f(z)\,dz = 0$ as well, 
contradicting that  $\int_{|z| = 1} {1 \over z}\,dz = 2\pi i$.

Comment: $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is just one example which cannot extends continuously to boundary of D ??  Can I define $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}~$ for every holomorphic function on the unit disc when it is on boundary of D?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $f(z)={1\over z}$ for $z\in\partial D$. Multiply by $z$, then
$$zf(z)-1=0 {\rm\ for\ all\ } z\in \partial D$$
By the maximum principle, we must have $$zf(z)-1=0 {\rm\ for\ all\ } z\in D$$ as well. Now evaluate at $z=0$, and you have a contradiction.

Comment: Can I generalize for every holomorphic function on unit disc?  I think it is only for $f(z)=1/z$. Do I misundertands something?

Comment: I have assumed that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the unit disk, of course, and that $f(z)=1/z$ on the boundary of the disk. A similar argument also works if $1/z$ is replaced by a function with a finite number of poles inside the unit disk.

Answer (score -2):

By maximum principle we get that the function $g(z)=zf(z)-1$ can take the maximum value as $0$, but it can have the value less than $1$ just like in case if $z=0$, $g(0)=-1$, why it is a contradiction?